# Convert Google Doc to pdf and send to email address

Tags: google-apps-script

I don't know how to make this. But I need a script that convert a certain Google Doc to PDF and then sends an email (with that PDF as an attachment) to a certain email address.

Could someone help please?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

See what is described here: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#sendEmail(String,String,String,Object)

```
// Send an email with a file from Google Drive attached as a PDF.
 var file = DriveApp.getFileById('1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz');
 GmailApp.sendEmail('mike@example.com', 'Attachment example', 'Please see the attached file.', {
     attachments: [file.getAs(MimeType.PDF)],
     name: 'Automatic Emailer Script'
 });
```

Comment: Is there a way to specify which pages get sent?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question about which page to send. Can you be more specific? Also, what doesn't work?